# NextJS useLayoutEffect not wait async function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, next.js

I want to check if the user is logged in on page reload (F5). To do this, I call the useLayoutEffect hook in the _app.tsx file:

```
  const { authenticated, setAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext)

  const fetchRefresh = async () => {
    const status = await AuthStore.checkAuth()
    if (status == 200) {
      setAuthenticated && setAuthenticated(true)
    } else {
      setAuthenticated && setAuthenticated(false)
    }
    return status
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
      fetchRefresh()
    }
  }, [])
```

My index.tsx is wrapped in a Layout where I call useEffect and check the user state from the context:

```
export const withLayout = <T extends Record<string, unknown> & IAuthContext>(Component: FunctionComponent<T>) => {
    return function withLayoutComponent(props: T): JSX.Element {
        const { authenticated } = useContext(AuthContext)
        const router = useRouter()

        useEffect(() => {
            if (!authenticated) router.push("/auth/login")
        }, [authenticated])

        return (
            <Layout>
                <Component {...props} />
            </Layout>
        );
    };
};
```

The order of the logs in the console is as follows:

1. useLayoutEffect(_app.tsx)
2. use effect (index.tsx)
3. complete the fetchRefresh function

The login page also has a useEffect that redirects to the "/" page if the user is logged in.
So when I reload the page, I have a flicker and a few redirects that I want to get rid of.

And another question, why?

```
setAuthenticated && setAuthenticated(true)
console.log(authenticated) // print false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reason is technical: you don't await for `fetchRefresh()`. It just runs async operation and promise returns is ignored, nothing rely/check it.

Second reason, `useEffect`/`useLayoutEffect` are not blocking rendering, and even does not expect async operations. So (even) if you do it as

```
useLayoutEffect(() => 
    if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
      await fetchRefresh()
    }
```

first render would still happen anyway, and with `authenticated == true`.

You need to change your logic in some way. Either add a boolean `isLoading` so first render would not show anything since data is still being fetched/verified. Or instead of boolean for `authenticated` you can use enum `yes|true|undefined` and for last value does not do/show anything. Or do something else.